# Sending jquery-mobile form data to an email address

Tags: forms, email, jquery-mobile, submit-button

I am new to programming.  I have built a multi-page form for an Android phone using jquery-mobile + phonegap.  The form looks and works great, but it seems I have now hit a dead end.

I want the submit button to send the (preferably formatted data) to a specific email address, but am not sure how to do this.  The Jquery-mobile documentation explains how to get or post to a url, but I really only want to send it to one or two recipients.

If I put a mailto:name@dom.com statement where the url is asked for it brings up the info in one long string in the native email client.

I'd give code examples, but at this point it is only the procedure I don't understand and am not sure it can be easily done.

Any helpful suggestions would be appreciated as I have exhausted my research sources without success.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to submit your form to the server-side script first and send your email from there.

In `PHP` on the server side you can use [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to achieve that. The better alternative - [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com).

On the client you can only use `mailto:`.